# bootstrap column centering in wordpress template

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap section in a wordpress template I'm trying to hack and it won't center columns on the 2nd line of a row.

Currently it shows 4 columns in the top row and then 2 underneath floated to the left. What I want is to have the 4 at the top still but the bottom two to be centered

Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
 <div class="row row-centered">
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

'example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's static six div on your main template
[try this](https://codepen.io/Shuree/pen/NWWjBWd)

If is not try last 2 div into one single `row` again and give a classname with `justify-content-center`. It will give what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference please visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ and try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">

   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-sm-3">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```